# FirebaseSmartReply: Not passing Expander filter

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am trying to integrate Firebase Smart reply into an android chat app but after a few messaging interactions, Smart reply doesn't generate responses again.

This doesn't explicitly throw an error, it just logs "I/FirebaseSmartReply: Not passing Expander filter" in the logcat

```
mFirebaseTextMessages.add(FirebaseTextMessage.createForRemoteUser(messageToDisplay, System.currentTimeMillis(), "a"));
suggestReplies();
private void suggestReplies(){
        mFirebaseSmartReply.suggestReplies(mFirebaseTextMessages)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<SmartReplySuggestionResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(SmartReplySuggestionResult result) {
                if (result.getStatus() == SmartReplySuggestionResult.STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED_LANGUAGE) {
                    // The conversation's language isn't supported, so the
                    // the result doesn't contain any suggestions.
                } else if (result.getStatus() == SmartReplySuggestionResult.STATUS_SUCCESS) {
                    // Task completed successfully
                    // ...

                    suggestionList.clear();
                    for (SmartReplySuggestion suggestion : result.getSuggestions()) {
                        String replyText = suggestion.getText();
                        Log.d(TAG, replyText);
                        suggestionList.add(replyText);
                    }
                    mSuggestionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        // Task failed with an exception
                        // ...
                    }
                });
    }
```

2019-05-19 23:20:03.235 9441-9640/ng.org.knowit.chatty I/FirebaseSmartReply: Identified language as: en
2019-05-19 23:20:03.246 9441-9705/ng.org.knowit.chatty I/FirebaseSmartReply: Not passing Expander filter

Answer (score 0):

This means the sensitive topic filter has triggered, which causes Smart Reply not to produce any responses. Because the input to the filter is the set of previous messages, you won't get any responses until the message that caused it has been pushed out of the most recent message history (or removed from `mFirebaseTextMessages` in some other way).